# Windows 8 OLEDB / ADO.NET drivers for Sybase ASE?

Tags: ado.net, oledb, sap-ase

Has anyone successfully installed Sybase OLEDB drivers and Sybase Central on a Windows 8 (64 bit) system? I've tried the installers on the Sybase website but they fail. Searches for "Windows 8" on the Sybase site and "Sybase Windows 8" on Google are bringing up nothing. We have a developer here who installed them on a Windows 7 system and then did an OS upgrade to Windows 8 so I know they will work. I would rather not uninstall Windows 8 and go that route if I can help it though.

Comment: I have the exact same problem... manual install?

Answer (score 3):

I managed to solve this! It seems like the actual GUI (written in Java) doesn't work in Windows 8, but there is a way to perform a console installation instead, which worked for me.

In the `Adaptive Server Enterprise 15.5 PC Client` installation CD (or whatever your source is), go to the folder `pcclient32` (or 64) and run this command: `setupConsole.exe -i Console`

Follow the instructions there and install it into your Sybase folder (mine was `c:\sybase`).