# Error while creating Sybase Connection from VB

Tags: excel, vba, sap-ase

I am trying to connect to Sybase ASE from VB and getting following error 
[image]

```
Function createConnection() As ADODB.Connection

Dim ConnectString As String Dim ConnString As String

Set conn = New ADODB.Connection 
    .Mode = adModeReadWrite
            .ConnectionTimeout = 15
            .ConnectionString = "Provider=ASEOLEDB;" & _
                                "Server Name=" & Range("DBServerName") & _
                                ";Initial Catalog=db;" & _                                
                                "User Id=user;" & _
                                "Password=password"


    .Open 
End With 
Set createConnection = conn    
End Function
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: I'd suspect the provider isn't installed then. Perhaps you have a different version - there are meny different options listed here: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sybase-ase-ole-db-provider-aseoledb/

Comment: Interestingly same code is working on a Windows 7 machine and it is not working on new Windows 10 machine, So I do suspect some installation is missing. Can anyone point to what installation may be required?

Comment: I can see below oledb provider installed                                                           
SAP ASE OLE DB Provider 15.7.0.1381

Key: \\HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{ab4e5d06-6a7d-3a45-aae4-863df036432f}

OLE DB Provider: SAP ASE OLE DB Provider 15.7.0.1381

ProgID: ASEOLEDB.15.7.0.1381

VersionIndependentProgID: ASEOLEDB.15.7.0.1381

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download & Install Provider

http://devzone.advantagedatabase.com/dz/content.aspx?key=20&Release=19&Product=15

use below commands to register provider

regsvr32 sybdrvodb.dll

regsvr32 sybdrvodb64.dll

Details:
http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc20116.1550/html/aseodbc/aseodbc43.htm

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you fist to check odbcad as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17153924/cannot-register-sybase-15-ase-ole-db-driver-on-windows-7).
If you can find any mention of ASEOLEDB there, then you just have problem either with the app using wrong type of drivers (32-bit vs 64-bit) or with a connection string.

But as the error message suggests, you might be missing just the provider - same problem as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13939317/windows-8-oledb-ado-net-drivers-for-sybase-ase). These libraries are usually part of these installations:

- SAP/Sybase ASE
- SAP/Sybase ASE PC Client CD
- SAP/Sybase ASE SDK

All of these can be acquired on [SAP portal](http://launchpad.support.sap.com/), however you need a login to that place as this software is accessible only on purchase. You can find [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01085.1550/doc/html/jon1242083230295.html?resultof=%22%41%53%45%22%20%22%61%73%22%20%22%4F%4C%45%22%20%22%6F%6C%22%20%22%44%42%22%20%22%64%62%22%20) a link of PC Client CD content (Sybase infocenter website) and a manual on OLEDB [here](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/topic/com.sybase.infocenter.dc00075.1570/pdf/oledb.pdf).
Unfortunately only freely downloadable ASE is for [Linux](https://www.sap.com/cmp/syb/crm-xu15-int-asexprdm/index.html), which is useless for you. Maybe you can find on that W7 machine installation media ...